# Write a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a string that looks like that:

```
 text = "Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4 Text5\n
         Here comes more test text\n
         and even more1 more2 more3\n
         tex text textt te tex\n
         1 2 3 4 5
         ..."
```

As you can see the data is separated by a single space character (and there are exactly 5 "texts" (I mean strings) in a row. I want to write a CSV table to make the data look nice. So that it looks like that:

```
 Col1    2     3     4     5
 Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4 Text5
 Here  comes more  test  text
 and   even  more1 more2 more3
 tex   text  textt te    tex
 1     2     3     4     5
```

There should be 5 columns and each string should be in a cell.
How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself at all? Did you see the python [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)?

Comment: Looks to me more like you want a fixed-column-width output table -- your output delimiter width varies between columns.

Comment: First step: `table = [line.split() for line in text.split('\n')]`. You're welcome :)

Comment: Are you looking for the data to display on screen or write to an actual .csv file?

Comment: Your example output is not actually a CSV, so I'm not clear on what you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try this

```
text = "Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4 Text5\n\
Here comes more test text\n\
and even more1 more2 more3\n\
tex text textt te tex\n\
1 2 3 4 5"
filecsv = open('csvfile.csv', 'w+')
filecsv.write(text.replace(' ', ';'))
filecsv.close()
```

Comment: This won't generate a csv file. Did you mean `filecsv.csv` and `,` instead of `;`?

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. I like it, it's light weight - but its ".csv"

Answer (score 1):

This code will write the data to a `csv` file.

```
text = """Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4 Text5\n
         Here comes more test text\n
         and even more1 more2 more3\n
         tex text textt te tex\n
         1 2 3 4 5"""

data = [x.strip() for x in text.split("\n") if x.strip() != ""]

columns = ["Col1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

# Write dictionary list to file
outfile = "d2.csv"

with open(outfile, "w") as fp:
    for key in columns:
        fp.write(key + ", ")

    fp.write("\n")

    for line in data:
        l = ", ".join(line.split())
        print l
        fp.write(l)
    fp.write("\n")
```

Output:

```
Col1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
Text1, Text2, Text3, Text4, Text5
Here, comes, more, test, text
and, even, more1, more2, more3
tex, text, textt, te, tex
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```